# Angular variable will not "unset" between function calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular setup that will set the value of a variable and will not let it go.  I'm trying to set/reset the value of a $scope variable between two function calls to http.  So basically:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
        $http({
          url:'http://localhost:3001/foo/api/v1/auth',
          method: 'post',
          data: JSON.stringify({email:$scope.user.email}),
          headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.status = data.status;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
        }) ...etc...
```

And then when that first one is done the html page changes accordingly and then I call another function:

```
  $scope.thirdPage = function(user) {
    var userStatus;
    var goCode = JSON.stringify({email:$scope.user.email, securitycode:$scope.userCode});
    $http({
      url:'http://localhost:3001/foo/api/v1/auth',
      method: 'post',
      data: goCode,
      headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {      
      //neither of these work
       $scope.status = data.status; //retains original value
       $scope.userStatus = data.status; //will not pick up data.status
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
      $log.warn("scopeErrorStatus: " + $scope.status);
    })
```

Angular will not let me re-set the value of `$scope.status` from one function to the next and it will not allow me to set a different variable to `data.status`.  Thinking the problem is that the AJAX query has not completed I have tried using $watch (no difference) and $apply (threw an error that seemed to be somehow related to the Bootstrap code that is also running).  Have declared the variables as local to the functions, global, etc. Pulling my hair out over this one.  Thoughts?

Comment: in success function of your second code you try to set `$scope.userStatus` instead of `$scope.status`. Is that what you want or is it an typo?

Comment: No...that's another thing I was trying.  Guess that's not clear from the post.  Will edit.  But my point is it will neither let me change $scope.status nor let me set another variable to data.status.

Comment: Why do you think so, maybe you should log the value of `data.status` and `$scope.status` at the relevant lines into the console and post the results here. Is it in your first or in your second piece of code? Is it on success or on error?

Comment: The first time $scope.status is set to the value "ok."  The second time the status should return "authorized" or "unauthorized" but I can't get it to be set to anything other than "ok."

Comment: can you try to `console.log(data.status + "/" + $scope.status)` before and after the relevant line?

Comment: Well, I'd follow steven's suggestion and log the values in all of the cases (both success and error functions). And especially what you receive (`data` etc) - it might be that your `data.status` **is** always ok, and what you want might be in an entirely different property.

Comment: WOW DO I FEEL DUMB, that console.log did the trick.  So Steven go ahead and answer for points and feel free to downvote me for being an idiot.

Comment: @steven, submit for answer points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step of debugging should be to output the value of `$scope.status` and of `data.status`. To see if the value is really not assigned.

So you should log both values before and after the relevant line to console to see whats going on.

```
console.log(data.status + "/" + $scope.status);
```

I cannot imagine that the assignment fails. So log the values to see what really happens.

Comment: Thanks Steven...and nice beard!

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the way primitives work with child scopes in Angular. I suspect you have created a child scope somewhere, and the value you want to update has been shadowed.

The way to fix this is to move your scope properties to an object. Such as:

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.status = "ok";
```

More on this here: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/

Comment: This is kind of more what I was expecting the problem to be and so +1 for the link, but the real problem is that I wasn't looking closely enough at the variables themselves so turned out to be simpler than I thought!

Comment: Ahh, usually I catch that, good call! In any case, I would still move your properties to objects in the long run. Glad you got it solved though :)